# Problems with Buttons in a Scrollviewer

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to add Buttons to my Scrollviewer, my result so far is negative, scrollviewer will not work. I tried wrapping around stackpanels but no luck. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks,

```
        <ScrollViewer Name="flippy" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1366" MinHeight="668" Name="GridA" Grid.Row="1">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Pics/Alfabetet/Appelsin.png" Stretch="None" />
                    <StackPanel Height="150" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="180" Width="179" Margin="10">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Pics/Alfabetet/storA.png"></ImageBrush>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Content="button2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="140" Width="121" Margin="10">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Pics/Alfabetet/litenA.png"/>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Height="103" Width="557" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="button3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="103" Width="553">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Pics/Alfabetet/Appelsin.fw.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Pics/Alfabetet/Appelsin.fw.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: edit: the Buttons do work, it's the Scrollviewer that's not working in case that was unclear.

Comment: Define not working, like the mousewheel doesnt work, or the scrollbars do/dont appear and it doesnt scroll?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't scroll to the next image. That's the problem. I tried wrapping this page in various grids and stackpanel, but it will not scroll to the next image i have waiting. The "indicators" on each side of the picture does not give a hint of that there are any more images. Sorry for the bad explanation. If I remove my buttons it does scroll to the next picture. What is the "correct" way of doing this? I'm so fresh on Windows Store apps.

Comment: If that's your actual code. You have a broken `<Image/>` tag. Look at the second `Image` in your code, see how it says `<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"    <StackPanel`? It's not closed or doesn't need to be there at all. That would be your issue. Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry, there must have been some error when i cut'n paste it. I updated the code now. I put my buttons in a stackpanel to align them correct horizontally. This is not the way it should be done?